# Merge records and remove duplicates in SQLServer 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

We have a table of orders with few duplicates in it. But the duplicates are not fully duplicates.

Lets say I have an orders table:

```
CREATE TABLE orders 
  ( 
     order_id             INT, 
     order_number         INT, 
     customer_id          VARCHAR(34), 
     tb_register_no       INT, 
     tb_customer_id       VARCHAR(7), 
     tb_customer_no       VARCHAR(10), 
     tb_store_no          INT, 
     tb_trans_no          INT, 
     tb_trans_category_id VARCHAR(4), 
     sales_associate_no   VARCHAR(5), 
     date_booked          VARCHAR(7) 
  ); 



INSERT INTO orders
    (`order_id`, `Order_number`, `Customer_Id`, `tb_register_no`, `tb_customer_id`, `tb_customer_no`, `tb_store_no`, `tb_trans_no`, `tb_trans_category_id`, `sales_associate_no`, `date_booked`)
VALUES
    (1, 1001, NULL, 3, NULL, NULL, 235, 1001, '2', '52279', '00:00.0'),
    (2, 1001, '0x331EFC0429A811E39742643150505996', 3, '3479899', '8883724945', 235, 1001, NULL, NULL, '00:00.0'),
    (3, 1014, NULL, 2, NULL, NULL, 235, 1014, '2', '52275', '00:00.0'),
    (4, 1014, '0x330E5A3429A811E39742643150505996', 2, '3479876', '8883722810', 235, 1014, NULL, NULL, '00:00.0')
;
```

So i need to have one order entry for all the ordres who have same `order_number,tb_register_no,tb_store_no,tb_trans_no,date_booked`. That means i need to merge records with order_id 1 and 2 into one records with filling the `NULLs` from other record. How can we do this?

This is to be done in SQLServer 2005. After merging rows like this i need to remove the other duplicate ordres(if we merge row with order_id 1 into 2 then row with order_id 1 has to be removed).

Comment: Don't post an image but the data as text. Then we can copy-paste it to [sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way you describe it - I'd say something along this line:

```
UPDATE O
    SET 
    Customer_Id = ISNULL(O.Customer_Id, O2.Customer_Id)
    ...remainder fields...
FROM dbo.orders AS O
INNER JOIN dbo.orders AS O2 ON 
                o.Order_number = o2.Order_number 
                AND o.order_id <> o2.order_id
```

This will update Order, with the first not-null field.
And then you can afterwards delete the duplicate.

Comment: your answer perfectly helpful for me.